# How do I enable lineweights for my symbology?

Tags: qgis

I imported an OSM shapefile of roads data. In the layer properties, I classified  the roads based on type (motorway, trunk, residential, etc.). I can assign colors but cannot assign lineweights. I can go through the motions of changing the lineweight but when I go back into the dialog to check the lineweight, it is reverted to a default value (0.26). How do I change  the lineweight based on feature type?

QGIS 2.10

Update 1 - Steps to reproduce...

1. Create a new document.
2. Import the roads OpenStreetMap shapefile (roads.shp).
3. Right-click on the roads layer, select `Properties`.
4. On the `Style` page, select `Categorized`.
5. From the `Column` list, select `type`.
6. Click `Classify`.
7. Right-click motorway, select `Change width`.
8. Set the `width` to `2.0` (type it).
9. Click `OK`.
10. Again, right-click `motorway`, select `Change width`.

The width is not 2.0. It's 0.26, the default value.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of 2.10.0 which seems to be fixed and will be shipped with 2.10.1. You can install the fixed version using qgis-rel-dev from OSGeo4W if you are using Windows.

In general, 2.10 has not been publicly announced yet (on qgis.org or the mailing list) most likely because some issues popped up which need to be resolved.

Comment: Just to confirm, it's definitely fixed in 2.10.1